# SQL performance hit when NOT joining

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, join

I'm trying to execute a select query over a fairly simple (but large) table and am getting over 10x slower performance when I **don't** join on a certain secondary table.

TableA is keyed on two columns, 'ID1' & 'ID2', and has a total of 10 numeric (int + dbl) columns.

TableB is keyed on 'ID1' and has a total of 2 numeric (int) columns.

```
SELECT
    AVG(NULLIF(dollarValue, 0))
FROM
    TableA
INNER JOIN
    TableB
ON
    TableA.ID1 = TableB.ID1
WHERE
    TableA.ID2 = 5
AND
    TableA.ID1 BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000
```

As soon as the join is removed, performance takes a major hit. The query above takes **0.016 seconds** to run while the query below takes **0.216 seconds** to run.

The end goal is to replace TableA's 'ID1' with TableB's 2nd (non-key) column and deprecate TableB.

```
SELECT
    AVG(NULLIF(dollarValue, 0))
FROM
    tableA
WHERE
    ID2 = 5
AND
    ID1 BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000
```

Both tables have indexes on their primary keys. The relationship between the two tables is One-to-Many. DB Engine is MyISAM.

Scenario 1 (fast):

```
id  stype   table   type    possKey key     kln ref                     rws extra
1   SIMPLE  TableB  range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4                           498 Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  TableA  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   schm.TableA.ID1,const   1
```

Scenario 2 (slow):

```
id  stype   table   type    possKey key     key_len ref         rows    extra
1   SIMPLE  TableA  range   PRIMARY PRIMARY 8                   288282  Using where
```

Row count and lack of any mention of an index in scenario 2 definitely stand out, but why would that be the case?

700 results from both queries -- same data.

Comment: How many results are from the first query, and how many results from the second query?

Comment: Provide [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) for both queries.

Comment: what does explain say? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your query, I'd say an index like this might be useful:

```
CREATE INDEX i ON tableA(ID2, ID1)
```

A possible reason why your *first* query is much faster is because you probably only have few records in `tableB`, which makes the join predicate very selective, compared to the range predicate.

[I suggest reading up on indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates). Knowing 2-3 details about them will help you easily tune your queries only by choosing better indexes.

Comment: Adding an index with the key columns in reverse order (ID2, ID1 -- rather than ID1, ID2) worked perfectly.

You're right that TableA contains 6,400,000 records while TableB has only 13,000.

Could you explain how switching the ordering of the columns in the index would yield the same benefit of joining on the smaller table? Is it related to having two indexes in both orders?

Comment: @KillerHurdz: It appears that `ID2 = 5` is a much more selective criteria than `ID1 BETWEEN 15000 AND 20000`. This means that when searching through the index's B-Tree, a much smaller data set can be selected *first* by filtering on `ID2`, and then further reduced *slightly* by filtering on `ID1`. If you reverse the columns, then you'll load tons of data from the disk into memory *first*, before significantly reducing it only afterwards. [This page](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates) has lots of insights